# Turning Off Keyboard's lights while in Bootcamp's Windows 8

Tags: keyboard, macos, bootcamp, windows

When I start Win8 (installed with bootcamp) the keyboard lights are **always** on. How do I **disable** this?

Is there a possible way to never ever let them turn on again? (Besides opening the hardware and cutting off the wires).

I have looked in power settings but didn't found anything helpful.

Comment: Try holding F5 to dim totally.

Comment: Try reinstalling the WindowsSupport files (which reinstalls the keyboard driver)

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found is to go into the power plan settings and go into advanced settings then under display disable adaptive brightness.

Comment: This doesn't affect the keyboard backlight?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do this without 3<sup>rd</sup>-party software such as [**Power Plan 7**](http://www.powerplan7.com/features_macbook.htm).

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/bootcamp.html

Comment: Is it possible to alter the SMC manually? That could possibly do the trick.

Comment: @ElRojito I'm not aware of any way to do that.